# Returning an error message other than the last one thrown in R

Tags: r, error-handling, assertthat

I have two functions that construct R S3 objects. One object encapsulates the other. When the user passes a bad `num` argument to `fun2()` it throws the error assertion in `fun2()`. I think it would be more informative for the user to see the message in `fun1()`. What are the options for preserving the message raised in `fun1()` and raising that instead of the message in `fun2()`?

```
fun1 <- function(num) {
  assert_that(num %% 2 == 0, msg = "num should be even")
  structure(num,
      class = "fun1-Class"
  )
}
fun2 <- function(text, num) {
  assert_that(class(num) == "fun1-Class", msg = "Bad Class")
  structure(list(text, num),
    class = "fun2-Class"
  )
}

fun1(1.2)
# Throws error "num should be even"

x <- fun2("myText", fun1(1.2))
# Throws error "Bad Class"
```

Traceback is below

```
 Error: Bad Class 
3.
stop(assertError(attr(res, "msg"))) 
2.
assert_that(class(num) == "fun1-Class", msg = "Bad Class") 
1.
fun2("text", fun1(1.2))
```

Comment: A quick fix is to add `force(num)` at the beginning of the body of `fun2`

Comment: @Aurèle Thank you! Adding that results in the expected error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@aurèle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6197649/aur%c3%a8le) answered this in the comments.

This happens because of the lazy evaluation of function parameters. `force(num)` will change the behavior and evaluate the first constructor.